# Feature selection using Random forest with importance / varImp functions with factor variables

Tags: r, types, classification, random-forest

For building a classification model, I am trying to select the most important features from the data set.
My data contains mixed attributes ( numerical and categorical).
I am planning to apply **(importance or varImp)** functions in R  after applying Random forest to select features from the data to improve the accuracy of my model.

My question is: **Can I apply Random forest directly on the data without transformation step   or  I have to convert categorical attributes into binary (0,1)**

I have applied Random forest with importance / varImp functions on a numeric dataset,  the model works fine,  but I am not sure about mixed data.

Comment: First, As the variable importance measures the decrease in accuracy if one column is removed, you should be fine. Have you tried is so far? Did you have any problems? Q could be flagged as off-toppic...

Comment: I applied  Random forest on numeric data set only. I want to improve the accuracy of the model, so I applied  importance function in R for choosing the most important features, the accuracy was improving, now I am going to apply the same method on mixed data, I need to know if I can apply it directly  (without converting the data from type to another type) or no

Comment: I think yes, as the VI measures are not effected by the data type.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to include factorial (even ordered) variables for variable importance measures and classification / regression in R.

See this reproducible example:

```
library(randomForest)

df <- iris
df$Petal.Width <- as.factor(df$Petal.Width)
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
# $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
# $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
# $ Petal.Width : Factor w/ 22 levels "0.1","0.2","0.3",..: 2 2 2 2 2 4 3 2 2 1 ...
# $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

rfmodel <- randomForest(x = df[,1:4], 
                        y = df$Species, 
                        importance = T)
importance(rfmodel)
#                 setosa versicolor virginica MeanDecreaseAccuracy MeanDecreaseGini
# Sepal.Length 11.266441   8.036164 13.480521            15.940870        14.152530
# Sepal.Width   6.394913   4.071819  5.076422             7.869699         2.880664
# Petal.Length 43.532850  39.802356 46.246262            60.663778        53.622069
# Petal.Width  14.272307  24.389310 19.109018            26.923048        28.617028
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use randomForrest function from [randomForrest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf) package you don't have to convert independent categorical variables into separate columns for each value.

Although, you need to ensure the dependent (predicted) variable is either a factor (for classification) or numeric (for regression).